# SQL query to join two tables with no repeated values?

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

```
Table 1                          
ID | NAME | WARD_ID|         
1     A      1         
2     B      1         
3     C      2           
4     D      2 

Table 2           
ID | MONTH1 | MONTH2 | WARD_ID|         
1     9          10        1         
2     6          11        1         
3     5          12        2           
4     13         14        2
```

I want to join this two table and produce the following output:

```
ID | NAME | MONTH1 | MONTH2 | WARD_ID|         
1      A       9       10        1         
2      B       6       11        1         
3      C       5       12        2           
4      D       13      14        2
```

In the ON condition of the query I have to keep WARD_ID equal for both the tables. I could not able to figure out the solution. Anyone have any experience with a query like this?

Comment: Why not join on `id`?  It seems more appropriate.

Comment: It is a mock table actually..Later I have to deal with large number of NAME attributes,then I can not join on ID...

Comment: I don't think you have a full relation to `JOIN` those two table together like you want. How can you relate `TABLE 2 ROW 2` to `TABLE 1 ROW 2` without it also relating to `TABLE 1 ROW 1`? There's nothing beyond `WARD_ID` to relate the tables.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from (select t1.*,
             (@rn1 := if(@w1 = ward_id, @rn1 + 1,
                         if@w1 := ward_id, 1, 1)
                        )
             ) as rn
      from (select t1.* from table1 t1 order by ward_id, id ) t1 cross join
           (select @w1 := -1, @rn1 := -1) params
     ) t1 join
     (select t2.*,
             (@rn2 := if(@w2 = ward_id, @rn2 + 1,
                         if@w2 := ward_id, 1, 1)
                        )
             ) as rn
      from (select t2.* from table2 t2 order by ward_id, id ) t2 cross join
           (select @w2 := -1, @rn1 := -1) params
     ) t1
     on t2.ward_id = t1.ward_id and t2.rn = t1.rn;
```

The subqueries enumerate the rows in each table.  The `join` then uses the enumeration.

This is much simpler in MySQL 8.0, using `row_number()`.

Comment: MySQL 8 will be a **HUGE** improvement, adding lots of things that should have been in MySQL for a long time already. :-/

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that `ID` is intended to be the same from both tables. If so, I think you can do a multi-condition join:

```
select * from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on t1.ID=t2.ID and t1.WARD_ID=t2.WARD_ID
```

Comment: This query just gives me duplicate values of the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
SET @rn:=0;
SET @rn2:=0;
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 AS rn1, t1.ID, t1.NAME, t1.WARD_ID
  FROM t1
  GROUP BY t1.WARD_ID, t1.NAME
  ORDER BY t1.WARD_ID, t1.NAME
) s1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT @rn2:=@rn2+1 AS rn2, t2.ID, t2.MONTH1, t2.MONTH2, t2.WARD_ID
  FROM t2
  GROUP BY t2.WARD_ID, t2.MONTH1,t2.MONTH2
  ORDER BY t2.WARD_ID, t2.MONTH1,t2.MONTH2
) s2 ON s1.WARD_ID = s2.WARD_ID
  AND s1.rn1 = s2.rn2
```

But it really doesn't reliably sort the tables to join the same rows every time. I still think there isn't a reliable/repeatable way to join the two tables the same every time.

============================================================

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa2db0/1   <<<< If `ID` can be used to reliably sort the two tables, you can use it in the `ORDER BY`s. I've added it in this Fiddle, and included rows in the setup that would fall before the existing records and potentially change the sorting. This also includes more records in `Table 2` than there are in `Table 1`, so would possibly result in duplicated rows. These new rows are ignored since they can't be matched between tables.

Comment: Can `ID` be used to reliably sort both tables? If so, it would make the query easier and more reliable to sort to join the two rows properly.